# i have written the code for updating my contacts by using content provider but its not updating my contact list

Tags: android

i have written the code for updating my contact list by progamming using content provider , whenever i try to insert new phone number its not updating , its showing me the previous phone number 
for reference i pasting the code which i have written

```
private void updateContact(String phone) {
        if (updateUri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "There is nothing to update, Please create a contact and then click update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ContentValues newPhone = new ContentValues();
            newPhone.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.TYPE_MOBILE);
            newPhone.put(People.NUMBER, phone);
            getContentResolver().update(updateUri, newPhone, null,null);
            Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Updated the phone number to: " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Updated the phone number");
        }
    }
```

i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of updateUri? 
It has to identify the record you want to update. E.g. updateUri could be the URI returned by insert(). The Android developer site has some examples on how to construct the URI here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: This the value iam geting in LOG 01-06 08:29:39.667: DEBUG/NativeContentProvider(502): updateURI content://contacts/people/128/phones/674